# Extract certain keys from array

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$array1 = [
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => 3
];
```

Sometimes, in this array, the keys `a` and `b` are set to `null`, so the array is like the following:

```
$array2 = [
    "a" => null,
    "b" => null,
    "c" => null
];
```

How can i get a new array with only keys `a` and `b` if they're not `null`, otherwise an empty array?

This should be the result:

```
$newArray1 = [
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2
];

$newArray2 = [];
```

Comment: Seems not multi-dimensional. However, do you have some data that might be null that is not on your 1st dimen?

Comment: No it has just one dimension